# UWP - Creating and Using RichEditBox (or any control) in non-UI Thread

Tags: uwp, ui-thread

Currently getting `"The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread"` **exception**.

I don't want to display this control at all, only to use it to translate richtext to plaintext or to apply colors/text styles to plaintext and get it out as richtext.

Is there any way to create a `RichEditBox` control in a non-UI thread?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create a control in a non-UI thread.

If you want to use the `RichEditBox` features, you can still create one in your UI but keep it hidden (`Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed`).

Answer (score 0):

> "The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread"

The common way to resolve this is using [`CoreDispatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher) class.The [`CoreDispatcher.RunAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync) method schedules the provided callback on the UI thread from a worker thread, and returns the results asynchronously. For example:

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    RichEditBox richEditBox = new RichEditBox();
    root.Children.Add(richEditBox);  
});
```

Check the document I linked for more details.